# property used in this inner product equality

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

For a vectors space over a field F, the length of a vector $\vec{u}$ is

$\mid\mid\vec{u}\mid\mid^{2}=\langle\vec{u},\vec{u}\rangle=\sum_\left(i=1\right)^n\langle\vec{u},\vec{e}_{i}\rangle\langle\vec{e}_{i},\vec{u}=\sum_\left(i=1\right)^n \mid\langle\vec{u},\vec{e}_{i}\rangle\mid^{2}$

Can someone explain to me how the last equality came to be?
is there a theorem or property that I'm not recalling?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\langle \vec e_i, \vec u \rangle = \overline{\langle \vec u, \vec e_i \rangle}$ we have $\langle \vec u, \vec e_i \rangle \langle \vec e_i, \vec u \rangle = \langle \vec u, \vec e_i \rangle \overline{\langle \vec u, \vec e_i \rangle} = |\langle \vec u, \vec e_i \rangle|^2$.

Comment: Do you know which property is this? It's obscure...

Comment: $\langle \vec u, \vec v \rangle = \overline{\langle \vec v, \vec u \rangle}$ by definition of complex inner product, and $z \bar z = |z|^2$ by definition of norm of complex numbers.

Comment: Well, my note made no mention about F being a complex field. It says "any field F"...
Note is authored by a physics professor.

Comment: I've never seen vector spaces over any other field than $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, so you can safely (especially in physics) assume that $F$ is one of those.